# How would I implement a login with my system for my api

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, jsp

I am trying to figure out a way to make a login with me feature for my api i plan on releasing in my city to connect businesses via their own website.

Let's say I own a database that has a table with users
Each user has a username an password and an email adress.
Lets say i have a user with username=x, password=y, email=z

I would like to create a webservice of some sort that when called from a web page it opens another tab(this can be implemented on the page itself), forces the user to login without providing the webpage the password the user has put in(to prevent external businesses to steal passwords).

So access would go as follows

- User clicks "login with your ExternalAccount"
- Gets redirected to the site that hosts "ExternalAccount"
- Puts in his username and password x and y
- Gets redirected back to the site he came from with the information x and z(username and email)
- The page he came back to gets the required information without getting the password

How can I achieve this?

It seems like you guys are not understanding where I am coming from. I want to be able to login from another site without that site stealing passwords.

So imagine my business is named RyanServices. RyanServices has RyanAccounts. RyanServices has alot of RyanAccounts. Other businesses(such as BobServices) want to work together with RyanServices, so BobServices wants to make it possible to log in with RyanAccounts on his website.

RyanServices has no problem with this but he does not want BobServices to know the passwords of RyanAccounts(only the usernames and emails) and therefor asks people who wish to use RyanAccounts on another site, to login via RyanServices.. Once logged in via RyanServices, BobServices may use information such as phone numbers, emails, date of birth from RyanAccounts but not the password.

Examples of this sort of system being used is like how on StackOverflow you have the option "Log in via facebook"

Comment: Thank you for disclosing it. Do you have any *specific* questions?

Comment: SO is more of a place to ask specific questions. Tutorials are typically much better at proving overviews of what needs to be done.

Comment: Im asking how can this be done? or if it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for OAuth. Googling for for OAuth will provide you with lots of references and implementations are available for most environments.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, i just needed the word :) much love